# Android: Date pickers listeners from null to active

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datepicker, listener

I have two date pickers in the same activity and they are connected to each other, as when the user change one date the other date picker date is changed directly
**Here are the listeners**

```
  //initialize period date picker with current date and on date change listener 
        periodDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, new OnDateChangedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker periodDatePicker, int currentYear, int currentMonth,int currentDay) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Number = 1;
            birthDayDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, null);
                birthDateCalculations();

            }
        });

        //initialize birth date picker with current date and on date change listener 
        birthDayDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, new OnDateChangedListener () {

            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker birthDayDatePicker, int currentYear, int currentMonth, int currentDay) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Number = 2;
                periodDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, null);
                periodDateCalculations();               
            }
        });
```

when one date picker listener is invoked , **I turn the other listener to the second date picker to null , my question is, *how can I make the listener that I turned to null to be active again***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
If you assign a variable for listeners you can reuse them. Also it seems you have variable name clash. When `OnDateChangedListener` is called there is a `currentYear/currentMonth/currentDay` function arguments and class member variables:

```
OnDateChangedListener periodListener = null;
OnDateChangedListener birthdayListener  = null;

periodListener = new OnDateChangedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDateChanged(DatePicker periodDatePicker, int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay) {
              Number = 1;
              birthDayDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, null);
              birthDateCalculations();
              birthDayDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, birthdayListener);
         }


birthdayListener = new OnDateChangedListener () {    
         @Override
         public void onDateChanged(DatePicker birthDayDatePicker, int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay) {
              Number = 2;
              periodDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, null);
              periodDateCalculations();               
              periodDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, periodListener);
         }
    });


birthDayDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, birthdayListener);
periodDatePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, periodListener);
```

Comment: I set the other to null because I dont want to make the two have the same date, I have some special calculations for the date picker that I set its listener to null

Answer (score 0):

Make the listener at class level and just use this when ever you want in code. 
The answer of cancer is correct.